# Exceptions handler design issues

Tags: java, exception, runtimeexception

Ok so I am trying to build a exception handler, and I can't for the life of me, figure out why its not working! I did more or less the exact same thing on a previous assignment and it worked fine.

So this is the exception handler class

```
package cst8284.asgmt3.scheduler;


public class BadAppointmentDataException extends RuntimeException{
    private static final long serialVersionUID =  1L;
    private String Description;

    public String getDescription() {
        return Description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String Description) {
        this.Description = Description;
    }
    public BadAppointmentDataException(String m, String e) {
        super(m);
        this.setDescription(e);
    }
    public BadAppointmentDataException() {
        this("Please Try Again","Bad Data Entered");
    }




}
```

and then to test a string I used a method that creates a pattern

```
private static boolean testPhone(String p) {
    Pattern pnum = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\-\\d{3}\\-\\d{4}"); 
    Matcher m = pnum.matcher(p);
    boolean b = m.matches();   
    return b;
}
```

It is making sure a phone number is entered correctly.  I've tested the method and it works fine.

BUT, when I do and if statement such as

```
if (!testPhone(phoneNumber)){
    throw new BadAppointmentDataException("why doesn't this","work");
}
```

I get a unhandled exception error and it just crashes pointing to the line that calls the `BadAppointmentDataException` as the failure!

Comment: show the error message with stack trace

Comment: Are you talking about a runtime error? You haven't included the code with the try-catch block where you handle the exception you're throwing.

Comment: Please show us a [Minimal Complete and Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) instead of snippets of code.

Comment: It doesn't crash, because it doesn't run, and it doesn't run because it doesn't compile. This is a compilation error. And `RuntimeExceptions` have nothing to do with it.

Comment: Are you sure you're using the correct exception class, then?  Using the class you posted, `void test() { throw new BadAppointmentDataException("foo", "bar"); }` compiles just fine for me.  Maybe you've got your previous assignment in your classpath, with a `class BadAppointmentDataException extends Exception` in there?

Comment: Also, whether it's a compile- or run-time error, it's always a good idea to include the full text of the error message in your question.

Comment: @user207421 "It doesn't crash, because it doesn't run, and it doesn't run because it doesn't compile." -  I was able to compile that code.

Comment: thanks guys, I'm sure you can tell I am a n00b but thanks to Jeff Scott Brown below I was able to get err fixed! I'm really astonished at how fast you guys get to work on this though! Appreciated!

Comment: "...thanks to Jeff Scott Brown below I was able to get err fixed" - Awesome.  Glad you got it straightened out.  Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your `BadAppointmentDataException` class is not an exception handler.  It is an exception.  You have to write code to handle the exception, typically in a `catch` block.  For example, this will result in an unhandled exception:

```
package demo;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // this will result in an unhandled exception
        doSomething();
    }

    private static void doSomething() {
        if (!testPhone("some bad phone number")) {
            throw new BadAppointmentDataException("why doesn't this", "work");
        }
    }

    private static boolean testPhone(String p) {
        Pattern pnum = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\-\\d{3}\\-\\d{4}");
        Matcher m = pnum.matcher(p);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        return b;
    }
}
```

This will handle the exception:

```
package demo;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (BadAppointmentDataException exc) {
            // put your exception handling logic here...
            System.err.println("An error has occurred");
        }
    }

    private static void doSomething() {
        if (!testPhone("some bad phone number")) {
            throw new BadAppointmentDataException("why doesn't this", "work");
        }
    }

    private static boolean testPhone(String p) {
        Pattern pnum = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\-\\d{3}\\-\\d{4}");
        Matcher m = pnum.matcher(p);
        boolean b = m.matches();
        return b;
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thank you! I was wondering about that, like I wasn't sure if I needed the try catch block or not, I tried it a few times as well but I'm thinking I did it in the wrong area.